# Jquery Datatable Hide delete button

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using

```
$('#AffiliatedContractorLookup').dataTable().makeEditable
```

I want to give user the ability to add a new record , so for that purpose I used,

`<div class="add_delete_toolbar" />`

But this toolbar displays both Add and delete button. I want to hide the delete button. How can I acieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but I had the same problem. I tried some solutions and here's one that worked for me: 
in the file databled-editable you have this line:

```
if (oDeleteRowButton == null && properties.sDeleteRowButtonId != "") {
                    oAddDeleteToolbar.append("<button id='" + properties.sDeleteRowButtonId + "' class='delete_row'>Delete</button>");
                    oDeleteRowButton = $("#" + properties.sDeleteRowButtonId);
                    oDeleteRowButton.click(_fnOnRowDelete);
                }
```

place it in comment, and the button won't be added

Answer (score 0):

Even easier:

```
#btnDeleteRow
{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: It's a good `CSS` solution, but the OP (Original Poster) wants to do it in `jQuery`.

Comment: Also, this won't disable the functionality. Anybody savvy with Firebug would be able to enable the button with a single click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

To have only the "Add" button simply replace

```
<div class="add_delete_toolbar" />
```

with

```
<button id="btnAddNewRow">Add</button>
```